# PHP Роутинг. Мультиязычность и определение модуля сайта (админ-панель/веб-сайт)

Tags: php, .htaccess, route

Доброй ночи. Ломаю голову и никак не могу понять как мне реализовать **мультиязычность** и переключение между **админ-панелью** и обычной версией сайта.
Начал писать свой роутер, ибо с фреймворками еще не очень умею находить общий язык, никак немогу разобраться.
Очень надеюсь что найдется человек, который поможет мне реализовать мой вариант роутинга. И так, опишу проблему и задачу:

Создаю сайт. Требуется сделать мультиязычность(3 языка) и админ-панель. Ссылки должны быть такого вида:
 *Обычная версия*

1. `http://web-site.com/`

   - `http://web-site.com/catalog/auto/`
   - `http://web-site.com/catalog/auto/product/product-url/`
   - `http://web-site.com/`
2. `http://web-site.com/ru/`

   - `http://web-site.com/ru/catalog/`
   - `http://web-site.com/ru/catalog/auto/`
   - `http://web-site.com/ru/catalog/auto/product/product-url/`

Если же в адресной строке добавить `/admin/`, то должен сработать редирект и подключать директорию с файлами админ-панели.

- `http://web-site.com/admin/`
- `http://web-site.com/admin/products/auto/`

Файл `.htaccess` содержит следующее:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Я хочу, чтобы при открытии сайта был, допустим, русский язык по умолчанию, то есть ссылка вида `http://web-site.com/` это русский язык, если пользователь выбирает другой язык, то все ссылки которые есть на сайте автоматически форматируются в указаную локаль, то есть :
`http://web-site.com/catalog/` форматируется в `http://web-site.com/en/catalog/`. Я без понятия как можно посредством php переделать все ссылки под нужную локаль.

Дальше мой роутер:

```
class Router {    
    public $URI = [];
    public $TEMPLATE; 
    public $MODULE = []; 
    public $LOCALE;

    function __construct() {
        self::parseQueryString();
    }

    function parseQueryString() {
        /**
         * Метод который парсит строку запроса, и возвращает массив $URI
         **/
        $parsedString = parse_url($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], PHP_URL_PATH);

        $parsedString = explode('/', $parsedString);

        $this->URI = $parsedString;

        return $this->URI;
    }

    function setTemplate() {
        /**
         * Этот метод должен запустить проверку на существование шаблона
         * если таков есть, то возвращает название шаблона, если нет 
         * то название шаблона ошибки
         **/
        $template = $this->TEMPLATE;

        if (!$this->checkTemplate($template, $module)) $template = 'error';

        return $template;
    }

    function checkTemplate($template, $module) {
        /**
         * Этот метод проверяет наличие файла (шаблона)
         * Возвращает TRUE | FALSE
         **/
        $checkPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/views/' . $module . '/';
        $checked   = false;

        if (file_exists($checkPath . $template . '.php')) $checked = true;

        return $checked;
    }

    static function redirect($path = NULL) {
        /**
         * Статический метод обычной перезагрузки.
         * Использую после отправки формы методом пост,
         * либо когда это нужно
         **/
        if (!$path) {
            $redirect = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header("Location: $redirect");
        } else
            header("Location: /$path");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Он еще не закончен, собственно по этому я пришел к вам. Надеюсь кто-то поможет дописать или объяснить как это сделать.

Первым делом роутер должен принимать и парсить адресную строку. Это я сделал.
Но теперь мне нужно определять и форматировать ссылки автоматически под нужную локаль. Например, пользователь приходит на сайт:
`http://web-site.com/` попадает на главную страницу с русским языком. Потом переходить в каталог товаром `http://web-site.com/catalog/` и переключает на английский язык, мне надо переадресовать пользователя на `http://web-site.com/en/catalog/` и в роутере принять этот `/en/` и передать его в переменную `$LOCALE` которую я потом смогу использовать для вывода нужной инфы в нужной локали.
Если же в адресной строке пользователь вводит `http://web-site.com/admin/` то его должно перекинуть на страницу авторизации админ-панели. Но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.
Структура папок у меня такая:

- `web-site`

  - `application`

    - `configs`

      - `config.php`
    - `controller`

      - `controller.php`
    - `core`[dir]

      - `Router.php`
      - `Database.php`
    - `models`[dir]

      - `CatalogModel.php`
      - `NewsModel.php`
      - и тд...
    - `views`

      - `web_site`[*виды страниц сайта для обычного пользователя*]
      - `control_panel`[*виды страниц админ-панели*]
    - `loader.php`
  - `css`
  - `img`
  - `js`
  - `uploads`
  - `index.php`

Файл `loader.php` подключает все нужные файлы в самом начале.
Потом я в файле `controller.php` запускаю свой роутер.
К сожалению, дальше я не знаю куда двигаться и что делать. Если нужно больше инфы, я предоставлю всё необходимое.

Comment: Почему в роутере не создать несколько условий?
Если сайт.ком то подгружаем один языковой файл
Если сайт.ком.ру то другой
???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В описанной вами структуре мне не совсем понятно почему у вас роутер подключается в контроллере. То есть как я понял последовательность такая

index.php -> loader.php -> controller.php -> router.php

За что в этой схеме отвечает контроллер? Просто подключение роутера?

Я думаю общий подход можно организовать таким образом:

index.php -> loader.php -> router.php -> controller.php

Где controller.php - это контроллер каждой отдельной страницы, то есть CatalogController, ProductController.

**Момент второй**
Зачем в роутере подключение шаблон? Основная и единственная задача роутера - разобрать url и подключить контроллер. А подключать необходимые шаблоны нужно в контроллере. Для этого можно сделать абстрактный класс Controller, реализующий метод, к примеру, render, который и будет подключать нужный шаблон.

**Мультиязычность**
В общем решение выглядит таким образом:

Распарсить url и если после адреса сайта найдено что-то похожее на локаль,   загружаем нужный языковой файл, а если не найдено загружаем стандартный.

В шаблоне весь статический вывод информации получаем через функцию, которая по коду достает нужный текст из языкового файла

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но предложеный вами вариант как раз таки и используется в MVC паттернах, в большинстве фреймворков. Я же не совсем могу понять как правильно пользоваться этим. Но пожалуй попробую сейчас что-то примерное сделать, раз никто больше не ответил

Comment: Так почему не ипользовать этот вариант?

Comment: я не могу понять как и где применять, допустим, методы которые достают информацию из бд на каждой из страниц (хедер, футер, сайдбары), еще несколько моментов которые я совсем не понимаю в этом паттерне)

Comment: Так задавайте конкретные вопросы. Выше я описал алгоритм загрузки до контроллера. По нему вопросов нет? Для каждой страницы вы создаете контроллер, наследуемый от основного - ContactController, CategoryController и т.д. Каждый контроллер по сути является отдельной страницей, который содержит в себе логику, получение данных из моделей, подключение шаблона. То есть внутри контроллера вы получаете данные из моделей, изменяете их, подключаете шаблон и передаете эти данные туда